# How to setup Grails and AngularJS partial templates

Tags: java, javascript, grails, angularjs, grails-plugin

I am realizing a project using **AngularJS for the front end**, and Grails for the backend.

- **Angular JS** => Single page application
- **Grails** => REST API to be used in the WebApp itself and 3rd party apps.

This is how I setup the project:

```
web-app
   |
   |_____ js ( angular controllers, modules, partial templates.)
   |
   |_____ images
   |
   |_____ css


grails-app
   |
   |_____ views ( in here I have my main view, the one I use at the first user request )
```

Rather than using the Resources Plugin, I prefer building my own front end with Grunt, and then I only link the final files inside the layout itself.

I structured the `js` folder in web-app to contain a `partials` folder with all the partial templates to be called within AngularJS

This is my pretty standard angular code to load the views:

```
angular.module('myapp', []).
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/invoices', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/invoices-list.html',   
        controller: InvoiceListCtrl
    })
    .when('/invoices/:invoiceId', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/invoice-details.html', 
        controller: InvoiceDetailCtrl}
    )
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/dashboard'}, {
        templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard.html', 
        controller: DashboardCtrl
    });
}]);
```

What happens is that Angular is unable to get those partial templates, since the partial folder is not copied in the tomcat `work` directory.

I don't know which other approach can be used for a Grails powered project.

Comment: Please improve your question - e.g. what have you tried; show some code...

Comment: I have a very similar issue except my Partials are contained within the web-app directory of a Grails Plugin instead of the Grails app.  Any one have any thoughts on how to reference them?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is that the static resource is not descended from the default grails-app directory so you need to include the full path from the document root, e.g. `templateUrl: '/partials/invoices-list.html',`

Here is my set up for ui-router:

```
App.config([
  '$stateProvider'
  '$urlRouterProvider'

  ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) ->

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/")

    $stateProvider
      .state('intro', {
        url: "/",
        templateUrl: '/templates/intro.html'
      })
```

Comment: Sorry I don't see how your implementation is different from mine. Can you please explain how do you structure your partial templates folders?

Comment: My structure is the same as yours.

Answer (score 0):

I serve my partials/views via standard ajax requests.

```
class ViewController {

  def invoiceList() {
    render(template: 'invoiceList')
  }
  ...
}

$routeProvider
    .when('/invoices', {
        templateUrl: contextPath + '/view/invoiceList',   
        controller: InvoiceListCtrl
    })
```

`contextPath` is derived from `${request.contextPath}` that I store in a global variable in my main gsp.

Comment: so you basically keep the usual structure of a standard grails project? How do you do to run your e2e tests? About the contextPath variable you use, if I can I would suggest to config your grails path to run under the main localhost, so you can avoid to pollute your JS global name space ;)

Answer (score 0):

By default, all the files in the `web-app` folder are copied to a folder called `static` in the `war`. 
(You can change this behaviour. See the [Grails Documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-resources/guide/9.%20Configuration.html)).

In your example, you can check the partial files in following urls.

```
http://localhost:8080/yourApp/static/js/partials/invoices-list.html
http://localhost:8080/yourApp/static/js/partials/invoices-details.html
http://localhost:8080/yourApp/static/js/partials/dashboard.html
```

So, what you need to do is to figure out the path to this files. Something like this:

```
angular.module('myapp', []).
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/invoices', {
        templateUrl: '../static/js/partials/invoices-list.html',   
        controller: InvoiceListCtrl
    })
    .when('/invoices/:invoiceId', {
        templateUrl: '../static/js/partials/invoice-details.html', 
        controller: InvoiceDetailCtrl}
    )
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/dashboard'}, {
        templateUrl: '../static/js/partials/dashboard.html', 
        controller: DashboardCtrl
    });
}]);
```

Its important to notice that the `templateUrl` path should not be related to JS file.

Another example:

```
grails-app
    views
        mydomain
            index.gsp
web-app
    js
        partials
            mydomain-detail.html
            mydomain-list.html
        controllers
            mydomain-controllers.js
```

The resources:

```
http://localhost:8080/myApp/mydomain/  
http://localhost:8080/myApp/static/js/partials/mydomain-detail.html  
http://localhost:8080/myApp/static/js/partials/mydomain-list.html
```

The route configuration:

```
angular.module('myapp', []).
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/list', {
        templateUrl: '../static/js/partials/mydomain-detail.html',   
        controller: MyDomainListCtrl
    })
    .when('/show/:id', {
        templateUrl: '../static/js/partials/mydomain-detail.html', 
        controller: MyDomainDetailCtrl}
    )
    .otherwise({
         redirectTo: '/list'
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

as an alternative to [James' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18893616/1496037) you may use GSP directly. See [my answer in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26861000/1496037).

Regarding `contextPath`: I would say that you automatically get the right context if you **don't** add the preceding slash.

```
templateUrl: 'view/invoiceList'
```

Best regards,
Björn

P.S. Sorry for adding this as a full answer, I would have preferred it as a comment to James'. However, the system denied me to add a comment :-(